# without using fab commandline argument can I use fabric api automated

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I do not want to use the fab command and don't use the fabfile & command line arguments.  I want to  make automated remote ssh using fab api by writing a python script.Can I automated this by writig python script?

Answer (score 0):

You can call your functions with importing your fabfile.py. At the end, fabfile is just another python script you can import. I saw a case, where a django project has an api call to a function from fabfile. Just import and call, simple as python :)

Comment: Actually I don't want to use fabfile.I want to write my own method and call that put and run function

Comment: Still, whatever you want to do, you an just import and call. As I said, fabric is just another module and fabfiles just another python scripts. You can import fabric and call run() like you'd call in a fabfile. But in order to run stuff, you might need to initialize fabric environment variables with username and password, just like in the fabfile.